# Internet latency: what do PENDING and FROM CACHE mean in Chrome Developer Tools Network tab

Tags: google-chrome, http-status-code-301, latency, http-status-code-302

I would like to confirm whether I'm understanding this correctly or not. I'm having severe latency issues when I type "google.com" into the Chrome address bar, but not when I do the same thing in other browsers. I've also downloaded Canary and have the same issue there.  I think the other browsers may be rewriting the URL client-side, avoiding the first two 301 and 302 errors. Plausible?

Does "pending" mean that the request has not yet been satisfied? And does "(from cache)" mean that the browser is looking on my PC for the file?

It took 21 seconds to return the 301 error for the "google.com" request and then another 19 seconds to return the 302 and the ultimate redirect to the full URL. Would this mean that the server(s) handling such requests are really overburdened?

And why are those images taking so long to fetch? 59 seconds, and still pending?

[image: Chrome Developer Tools Network tab screen capture]

Comment: And what does Pending mean when the Size says "(from cache)". Shouldn't the Time column show how long it took to load from cache?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is what it means:

- PENDING: the file has yet to be downloaded from the network, and Chrome is making a request and trying to download it.
- FROM CACHE: the file has been downloaded and cached from a previous visit to this page, and Chrome loaded it from the cache

Did this problem get resolved? Was this for one particular day - when Google happened to be down? Most loads, especially for Google's home page, should be fairly fast.

Comment: But surely the big mystery is what do both of these at the same time mean?

Comment: I have a question, how browser decide whether to load resource from cache or not? I mean, sometimes i set `cache-control`, so `304` request is expected. So what makes browser decide to load resouce from cahce instead of sending the request?